# Mapping first element of certain type to a field

Tags: java, xml, deserialization, simple-framework

My xml file:

```
<x>
  <a>some value</a>
  <a>some other value</a>
  <b>some value</b>
  <c>some value</c>
</x>
```

I need to deserialize it to a class keeping only the *first* `a` tag value:

```
@Root()
public class X {

    //???   
    protected String a;

    Element(name="b")
    protected String b;

    Element(name="c")
    protected String c;
}
```

I have tried several attributes but I couldn't get anything useful. Any advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an inline list of `<a>` elements and then get the first `<a>` element of the list.

Try something like that:

```
@Root()
public class X {

    @ElementList (inline=true, entry="a")
    private List<String> aList= null;

    Element(name="b")
    protected String b;

    Element(name="c")
    protected String c;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I came up to. But, still, it seems strange that I cannot just use an XPath query and get the first element... I'll try something else and (maybe) update the post. Meanwhile, thanks.